# DB2 FUNCTION EXCEPTION

Tags: sql, exception, db2

I'm converting  Oracle plsql function into DB2 plsql function.Below I mentioned the structure of Oracle and DB2 query.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FUNCTION_NAME (IN PARAMETER1 DATATYPE)
                    Return varchar(4000) IS
                    N_COLUMN1 varchar(1);
                    N_COLUMN2 INT;
                    N_COLUMN3 VARCHAR(2000);
                    BEGIN 
                    SELECT A.COLUMN1,A.COLUMN2 INTO N_COLUMN1,N_COLUMN2 FROM TABLE A WHERE A.COLUMN1=PARAMETER1;
                    IF N_COLUMN1 = 'A' then  N_COLUMN3:= 'NEW_A';
                    ELSEIF N_COLUMN1 = 'B' then  N_COLUMN3:= 'NEW_B';
                    END IF;
                    exception when others then N_COLUMN3:= 'OTHERS'
                    RETURN N_COLUMN3;
                    END;
/
```

DB2 query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FUNCTION_NAME (IN PARAMETER1 DATATYPE)
                    Returns varchar(4000)
                    BEGIN 
                    declare N_COLUMN1 varchar(1);
                    declare N_COLUMN2 INT;
                    declare N_COLUMN3 VARCHAR(2000);
                    SELECT A.COLUMN1,A.COLUMN2 INTO N_COLUMN1,N_COLUMN2 FROM TABLE A WHERE A.COLUMN1=PARAMETER1;
                    IF N_COLUMN1 = 'A' then set N_COLUMN3= 'NEW_A';
                    ELSEIF N_COLUMN1 = 'B' then  set N_COLUMN3= 'NEW_B';
                    END IF;
                    exception when others then set N_COLUMN3= 'OTHERS'
                    RETURN N_COLUMN3;
                END;
```

I'm getting error on Exception part.I searched over internet and i'm getting **DECLARE type HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION**  they provide this syntax and mentioned before execution part need to declare this one.i'm not sure what word i need to use in place of **type**.can anyone help me what is the equaivalent DB2 syntax for **exception when others**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on where you want to pass the control in your code after the handler invocation.
Look at the [handler-declaration](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-compound-sql-compiled#sdx-synid_handler-declaration) description.
Below is a possible example of the function code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FUNCTION_NAME 
(
  IN PARAMETER1 VARCHAR (1)
)
Returns varchar(4000)
BEGIN
  declare N_COLUMN1 varchar(1);
  declare N_COLUMN2 INT;
  declare N_COLUMN3 VARCHAR(2000);
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
      -- The last statement executed in the function 
      -- when the handler fires.
      -- The control is passed out of the function body
      -- since the handler is declared 
      -- in the main BEGIN END function block.
      RETURN 'OTHERS';
    END;
  
  SELECT A.COLUMN1,A.COLUMN2 
  INTO N_COLUMN1,N_COLUMN2 
  FROM 
  --TABLE A 
  (
    VALUES
      ('A', 0)
    , ('A', 0)
    , ('B', 0)
  ) A (COLUMN1, COLUMN2)
  WHERE A.COLUMN1=PARAMETER1;
  IF N_COLUMN1 = 'A' then 
    set N_COLUMN3 = 'NEW_A';
  ELSEIF N_COLUMN1 = 'B' then
    set N_COLUMN3 = 'NEW_B';
  END IF;
  --exception when others then set N_COLUMN3= 'OTHERS'
  RETURN N_COLUMN3;
END
```

```
SELECT P, FUNCTION_NAME (P) AS F
FROM (VALUES 'A', 'B') T (P)
```

| P | F |
| --- | --- |
| A | OTHERS |
| B | NEW_B |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FGNu-ufM)

Comment: I have small doubt in result if P value is A then How F value is 'OTHERS'.it might be 'NEW_A'?

Comment: No way to return 'NEW_A' in this example. I showed it to make the handler fire, since SELECT INTO can't be executed successfully, if it returns more than one row. BTW I don't remember if Oracle triggers exception if no rows is returned. Db2 throws warning, not an exception, and this handler doesn't fire.

Comment: Im getting below error while executing your query SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END 
".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.9.78